# How to hide web service API key?

Tags: oracle, web-services, api, oracle-apex, api-key

I'm using oracle apex 4.2.6.
I have a web service that I want to use. ( Web service is not mine ) 
I need to hide the API key when calling it. I want to know how.

Can I create my own web service that will call this one and then send my API key with the call? If yes , how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to consume web services on the back-end (and hiding your api key).

1) Under `Shared Components` --> `Web server reference` --> `Create`
You can consume REST / Based on WSDL and Custom.  Then you can reference the Web service in your APEX application and the back-end does the call.

2) Create a custom PL/SQL function/procedure that uses `UTL_TCP` or `UTL_DBWS` (or `UTL_HTTP` if it's a simple REST service) to call the web-service and crunch the response.

http://www.oraclecafe.com/2014/08/calling-wsdl-webservice-from-plsql/

If the web service is simple then going with option 1) would be the quickest way.

[Creating and Using a Manual SOAP Web Service in Your Application](https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:102083768954301:::24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PROD_SECTION_GRP_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:5815,,24)

Comment: Ty , I'll check it out tomorrow !